# PhpStorm: Show "Run" output as rendered HTML (in an internal browser)?

Tags: php, html, browser, console, phpstorm

Is it possible to view the output of a PHP script in the [Run Tool Window](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/run-tool-window.html) as rendered HTML?

I have an application that generates HTML output and currently I need to copy it from the console, save it in an HTML file and open that file in a browser to view the rendered output.

Eclipse PDT has a view called "Web Browser", for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no -- PhpStorm (and any other IDE built on IDEA platform AFAIK) does not have such functionality.

You may submit Feature Request ticket to their [Issue Tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI) .. but I doubt that it will be implemented any time soon (very limited usage case, as far as I see it right now).

---

I may suggest to save such output into `.html` file directly (if you can edit such script -- at least during your debug/test sessions) and open it in browser (then simple "Refresh" in browser will do the job).

Answer (score 2):

If you are executing the PHP file in the console and then manually copying the html code and saving it to a file and finally running it, running this command might help :

```
php file.php | cat > file.html | google_chrome file.html
```

Or maybe you can just do :

```
php file.php | cat > file.html
```

and refresh the page in the browser.

In this case you won't have to manually copy the code each time.